# Additional methods in the Object Class

Tags: java, object, methods

The Object class has a number of methods such as equals, hashCode, notify, wait etc.

What methods do you think are missing from the Object class and why? Are there any additional methods you wish it had?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it should have any *extra* methods... in fact, [I think various methods that *are* there shouldn't be there in the first place](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/05/redesigning-system-object-java-lang-object.aspx).

One problem in Java is that a lot of types (such as `HashMap`) always use the hash code and equality methods on the keys directly - it would be much better if Java had an interface like .NET's `IEqualityComparer<T>` that anything wanting to perform hashing/equality comparisons could delegate to.

Comment: You can get at the "bare" hash code using `System.identityHashCode()` in Java.

Comment: I tought System.identityHashCode() was there to get this bare hascode anyway?

Comment: I've just read your article. From one hand you talk about really reasonable things but from another I think it can enlarge java entry threshold.